# Writing efficient functions for data.tables that replace by reference

Tags: r, function, replace, data.table, multiple-columns

I have a data.table which contains several binary columns with the same values that I would like to recode in one operation.  I have modified a function that was originally written for data.frames, but am not sure if I am really capitalizing on the speed of data.table with the way I have modified it: specifically I suspect the function might still be copying values.

How can I make sure that the function replaces values by reference?

Here is a toy data set:

```
# Example data:
id <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
fruit <- c("apple", "orange", "banana", "strawbery", "rasberry")
mydate <- c("2015-09-01", "2015-09-02", "2015-11-15", "2016-02-24", "2016-03-08")
eaten <- c("y", "y", "n", "y", "u")
present <- c("n", "n", "y", "y", "y")

dt <- data.table(id, fruit, mydate, eaten, present)
dt[, mydate := as.Date(mydate, format = "%Y-%m-%d")]
dt[, sex := c("m", "f", "f", "m", "f")]

# Columns to update:
bincols <- c("eaten", "present")
```

Before recoding, the data looks like this:

```
> dt
   id     fruit     mydate eaten present sex
1:  1     apple 2015-09-01     y       n   m
2:  2    orange 2015-09-02     y       n   f
3:  3    banana 2015-11-15     n       y   f
4:  4 strawbery 2016-02-24     y       y   m
5:  5  rasberry 2016-03-08     u       y   f
```

Here is the function:

```
recode.multi <- function(datacols, oldval, newval) {
  for (i in 1:length(datacols)) {
    datacols[datacols == oldval[i]] = newval[i]
  }
  datacols
}
```

... applied to the data:

```
dt[, (bincols) := lapply(.SD, recode.multi, oldval = c("u", "n", "y"), newval = c(NA_real_, 0, 1)), .SDcols = bincols]
```

... and the output, which updates the values as desired but not sure if it is copying the columns during this process?

```
> dt
   id     fruit     mydate eaten present sex
1:  1     apple 2015-09-01     1       0   m
2:  2    orange 2015-09-02     1       0   f
3:  3    banana 2015-11-15     0       1   f
4:  4 strawbery 2016-02-24     1       1   m
5:  5  rasberry 2016-03-08    NA       1   f
```

I tried changing the last '=' in the function to ':=' but got an error re checking whether 'datacols' was a data.table.  Adding a clause to the function to check if is.data.table == TRUE didn't solve the problem (same error returned).

Any thoughts on the most data.table appropriate way to approach this function would be much appreciated.

Comment: Unsure about the copying, but this is a fine bit of code. I am unsure what you mean here: "I tried changing the last `=` in the function to `:=`." Which `=` were you trying to change?

Comment: I tried: `recode.multi <- function(datacols, oldval, newval) {
  for (i in 1:length(datacols)) {
    datacols[datacols == oldval[i]] := newval[i]
  }
  datacols
} `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to Frank's but lets the arguments be passed to a function that builds the translation vector and returns the translation. You don't need to do the loop inside the function since the `lapply` , the `:=`, and the .SDcols  functions are doing the looping inside `[.data.table`.

```
recode_dt <- function(datacol, oldval, newval) 
    { trans <- setNames(newval, oldval)
     trans[ datacol ]   }

dt[, (bincols) := lapply(.SD, recode_dt, oldval = c("u", "n", "y"), 
                                         newval = c(NA_real_, 0, 1)), 
     .SDcols = bincols]
dt
#===============
   id     fruit     mydate eaten present sex
1:  1     apple 2015-09-01     1       0   m
2:  2    orange 2015-09-02     1       0   f
3:  3    banana 2015-11-15     0       1   f
4:  4 strawbery 2016-02-24     1       1   m
5:  5  rasberry 2016-03-08    NA       1   f
```

Note that your columns were not actually factors as it appeared you thought from one of your comments. They might have been had you built a data.frame as an intermediate step.

Comment: Interesting, the columns have named elements inside the RHS of `LHS := RHS`, but not after assignment. I mean `dt[, str(lapply(.SD, recode_dt, oldval = c("u", "n", "y"), 
                                         newval = c(NA_real_, 0, 1))), 
     .SDcols = bincols]`

Comment: That's not really much different than data.frame behavior. Names usually get thrown away, except for names of the first column that then get turned into rownames.

Comment: +1 for the use of setNames, I was thinking there might be a way to use 'set'.  I also like that it automatically converted the updated vectors from character to numeric as well.

Comment: It will return a vector of the same class as newval. Frank had a good point that supplying integer might be better. Also setNames is not a data.table function, despite its first three letters.

Answer (score 2):

I would do...

```
recodeDT = data.table(old = c("u", "n", "y"), new = c(NA_integer_, 0L, 1L), key = "old")

dt[, (bincols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) recodeDT[.(x), new]), .SDcols = bincols]
```

I think it's better to store any finite remapping in a table for clarity, but I don't know if it is more efficient. If you were storing your variables as factors, you could simply tweak the levels, which should be very fast. You could use `setattr(x, "levels", z)`, maybe.

*Side note:* You probably want to code these as integers instead of floats.

Comment: Thanks - hadn't thought of using a keyed lookup table approach.  I have avoided converting character vectors to factors, because of the difficulties encountered if adding extra levels, but can see how this would be efficient for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

In order to determine if my original solution was copying values or not, I applied mine, Frank and 42's solutions to my real data set which has 8933 observations and 150 columns to update with the function.  Results from `system.time` below:

@Amy M: 332.82 seconds

@Frank: 0.15 seconds

@42 (original):    4.13 seconds

@42 (with @Frank's modification): 0.05 seconds

Both Frank and 42's solutions are far faster than mine (so mine must be copying).

I have reprinted the fastest solution (42 with Frank's modification) below:

```
recode.multi <- function(datacol, oldval, newval) {
  trans <- setNames(newval, oldval)
  trans[ match(datacol, names(trans)) ]
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting result. Maybe if you switch the last line of -42's function to `trans[ match(datacol, names(trans)) ]` it will be faster. I guess the number of distinct values and the number of times each distinct value repeats in your data might matter.

Comment: Or just rewrite the entire function as `newvals[ match(datacol, oldvals) ]`

Comment: I couldn't get your second suggestion to work, but modifying the last line of 42's function does result in a gain in speed: time elapsed is 0.05 seconds.